# Using Kubernetes or easier orchestration tools

Tags: kubernetes, containers, orchestration

Hoping that there is some good insight into how to handle orchestration amount microservices in an on prem smaller company environment. Currently, the systems that we are looking to convert from monolithic to microservices like the rest of the world :).

The problem I'm having with as an architect, is justifying the big learning curve and server requirements with the resources we have at the moment. I can easily see us having 50ish microservices, which I feel could be on that line of using kubernetes or not.

The thing is, if we don't, how do we monitor if it is on-prem. We do use Azure Devops, so I'm wondering if this would safice for deployment parts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to a debate over essential vs accidental complexity. The verdict is in from companies that k8s strikes a good balance vs swarm and other orchestrators are barely talked about in the industry.

https://www.reactiveops.com/blog/is-kubernetes-overkill

The platforms that build on kubernetes are still emerging to offer a simpler interface for those wanting a higher level of abstraction but aren't mature enough yet. GKE offers a very easy way to just deal with workloads, AKS is still maturing so you will likely face some bugs but it is tightly integrated with Azure Devops.

Microsoft is all-in on k8s although their on-prem offering doesn't seem fully fledged yet. GKE on-prem and Openshift 4.1 offer fully managed on-prem (if using vSphere) for list price of $1200/core/year. https://nedinthecloud.com/2019/02/19/azure-stack-kubernetes-cluster-is-not-aks/

Other ways of deploying on prem are emerging so long as you're comfortable with managing the compute, storage and network yourself. Installing and upgrading are becoming easier (see e.g. https://github.com/kubermatic/kubeone which builds on the cluster-api abstraction). For bare metal ambitious projects like talos are making k8s specific immutable OSes (https://github.com/talos-systems/talos).

AWS is still holding out hope for lock-in with ECS and Fargate but it remains to be seen if that will succeed.

Comment: Thank you very much @user578582. A lot of great insight and I'll be reading the items above. So it sounds like there are some good hosted options (and I get that's where the wold is going). I think where I am stuck is that we have regulations and risk department that is still weary on moving anything critical out in the cloud as of today. What are your thoughts of a "Crawl, walk, run approach"? My thoughts are if we do a few microservices and see how it goes (crawl), Then start using monitoring and heartbeats/monitor built into Microsoft (walk) and then start implementing orchestration (run).

Comment: You hear different thoughts on how fast to go.

At this point you're probably better off picking a few VMs, a suitable project and just installing k8s (for dev environments at least). There are many banks using k8s in prod so it works although they've probably spent a lot on consultants to tweak the knobs for them. 

There is a quick win if you can set Azure Devops up to provide PR environments on every pull request. With an environment up and running you can have a concrete way of learning and can let the security and network folks prod it for a few months.

Comment: Yea. I know other banks are. We are a credit union with less resources and different regulations, but also risk team that is just getting used to the cloud. I'll mull this over a bit and look at the resources/ effort. I'm just concerned about the learning curve. I'm at devintersection right now and sat in a few k8 clases and it is a huge solution. Thanks for the thoughts. if you have any other thoughts, very much appreciated!

Comment: You'll know what works best for you. A couple of other random thoughts - if you use VMWare they're all in on k8s and have acquired two k8s companies recently so can offer good support. Most conservative companies seem to be planning to modernise on-prem and then move to cloud whenever suits. The benefits of k8s aren't really there unless the apps are modernised (although there are tools like GKE Migrate to import monoliths to k8s). So in a solution you ideally want to be able to install on-prem and then add workloads in the cloud. All providers (Redhat, GCP,VMWare) offer this hybrid strategy.

Comment: five times as expensive to run a monolith in the cloud vs on-prem. So it only makes sense to move a monolith into k8s as a staging post while you modernise. The approach of the consultancies is to do an app inventory and then decide which apps will be modernised and moved (over say 18 months) and which ones are too difficult and might be left to die.

Comment: Thank you for all the info @eamon1234. really appreciate your insight and like the onprem => cloud approach. i think that coupled with VMware options will really help our business case. One more question for you. What are your thoughts on the best way to implement on a small scale? How big should the cluster and how many servers are a good starting point in your opinion? Thanks again!

Comment: No prob. If you're just toying with it, you can get away with everything on one VM. If you'd like something more representative - go with 3 small (2 core) master VMs on different bare metal machines. For the workers, you can size them based on your workload needs - you want all your workloads to still be operational if one or two nodes disappear. As such, go with say 3-5+ nodes sized to whatever your workload requirements are. People tend to start off with multiple small clusters and migrate to a smaller number of progressively larger ones as they gain confidence. Adding nodes is easy.

Comment: I'd also like to add there are some container orchestrators that aren't based on kubernetes that might be a good fit for you :) check out https://cycle.io - which will allow you to easily manage infrastructure across multiple cloud providers as well.